# What types are binary incompatible in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I was wondering if anyone knows which types are binary compatible or incompatible in Postgres.

I'm particularly interested in cases where a `CREATE CAST` from one type to another could cause Postgres to crash.

If someone happens to have a pointer to a matrix showing type (in)compatibility, that would be ideal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data types that are binary-compatible generally already have `WITHOUT FUNCTION` casts defined for them.

A cast via a function is always safe, and not going to cause a problem.

If you want to add new `WITHOUT FUNCTION` casts, the only real reference is the source code, examining compatibility on a type-by-type basis.

Comment: I noticed that the pg_cast table records possible casts from one data type to data type:   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/catalog-pg-cast.html Some implicit conversion types appear here:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Type_conversion.html